# Secure and authorize GET request request from nginx/nchan to auth server

Tags: nginx, nchan

I am new to Nginx and nchan.
I have a typical use-case of pub-sub model based on Nginx/nchan where there are multiple subscribers and a single publisher. Subscribers subscribe to Nchan server via a websocket wss API call.
I want to allow only authorized nodes to be allowed to subscribe to Nchan. I know that there is proxy_pass in Nginx where I can rely on an external auth server to send 2xx to authorize a request, but there is a problem:

**The GET request itself from Nginx/nchan to my auth server needs to be authenticated/authorized so that not everyone is allowed to call the auth request.** Or take it like this: I cannot expose an open API on my auth server because of security concerns.

The subscribe requests can have an Auth token, which can be validated by auth server. Is there a way in Nginx by which I can parse the request received as subscribe request and pass it to auth server?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lua script and use something like this

```
location ~ "^/subscribe" {
    access_by_lua_block {
      //check headers/cookie for authorization token 
      //validate token
    }

    nchan_subscriber;
}
```

To rely on an external authorization service. You can use lua to proxy the request

```
location ~ "^/sub" {
    access_by_lua_block {
      local res = ngx.location.capture(location, options)
      if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
        return 
      end

      if res.status == ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED then
          ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
          return
      end
    }

    nchan_subscriber;
}
```